# JQuery - Open a different picture depending on the image clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, lightbox

So I created this script (albeit with a tutorial, I'm still new to JQuery) to open a lightbox for a picture when clicked. What I didn't think about was that this script will only open one picture regardless of the one clicked. Can anyone point me in the right direction where I might be able to figure out how to change this script so that when I click on the picture, it opens the correct, full picture. All the code is below.

HTML

```
<div class="backdrop"></div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="close">X</div>
    <img class="big_img" src="../pics/placeholder.png">
</div>

<div>
    <ul class="body">
        <li class="responsive">
            <div class=image>
                <a href="#" class="lightbox"><img class="gallery" src="../pics/placeholder.png"></a>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: .0;
  filter:alpha(opacity=0);
  z-index: 50;
  display: none;
}

.box {
  top: 20%;
  position: fixed; /* Lightboxes usually use position: fixed. */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  z-index: 51;
  padding: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;
  display: none;
}

.close {
  position: fixed;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.big_img {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.lightbox').click(function(){
            $('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
            $('.box').animate({'opacity':'1'}, 300, 'linear');
            $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block');
        });

        $('.close').click(function(){
            close_box();
        });

        $('.backdrop').click(function(){
            close_box();
        })
    });

    function close_box()
    {
        $('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
                $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none');
            });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gunjalray89/p4bx5ogt/       check this

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is open the big picture when a corresponding thumbnail is clicked. But you haven't anywhere mentioned which thumbnail is clicked so your function doesn't have idea which one to open. Also your function always opens same image you should change the src of image. Try this

```
<a href="#" class="lightbox"><img class="gallery thumbnail" src="../pics/placeholder.png"></a>
```

and in jquery do this

```
$(".thumbnail").click(function() {
   var image = $(this).attr("src");
   $('.big_img').attr("src",image);
   $('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
   $('.box').animate({'opacity':'1'}, 300, 'linear');
   $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block');
});
```

And rest is same.

Hope this helps. If there is any query feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks! That helped a ton. Quick follow up question, I'm trying to understand the script, and if I'm right, when ".thumbnail" is clicked, it automatically changes the big_img source to display whatever was clicked?

Comment: If you look at the script it is very simple. first we get the source of which image was clicked and save it to a variable image. then we change the image source for our big image. rest you understand. 

Please approve the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gunjalray89/p4bx5ogt/)

> This is solution for your problem. and add this script above your
>   HTML.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```